# Using Android-Vision to detect Hebrew

Tags: android, mobile, ocr, android-vision

I'm trying to create a simple application such as in the tutorial for the android vision API, only to recognize Hebrew, instead of English.

so far, from what i searched [mobile vision api](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/vision/text/package-summary), and from playing around with other languages, the application recognize many Latin based languages (French, Spanish, for example) but no non-Latin character languages i tried (Chinese, Hebrew, Arabic comes to mind).

the question is, is it possible to use Google's mobile vision to read non-Latin text? if yes, how would i change my simple app to read other type of characters? and if not, what are my alternatives? i have found tessaract and Google cloud vision, but i prefer to have as little interaction with outside sources as i can, i want the app to be installed and used freely without relaying on outside engines or servers, any help and pointing in the right direction is appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

Mobile vision OCR doesn't support non-latin languages.
here's a link to official documentation. 
https://developers.google.com/vision/text-overview

You can use Google Cloud Vision for the required purpose but it would require internet connectivity. For now, most of the OCR supported APIs require internet connectivity, If you find any with more language support as compared to Mobile vision, please answer to your question here.